# Getting the number of <video> tags on page with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've done some searching and I can't seem to find a solution.

I want to write a script that counts the number of `<video>` tags currently on the page and then run some other Javascript according to the amount of tags.

Don't even know where to start with this (I'm quite new to JS).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName), which returns a HTML Collection. In turn, you just count the length of the collection:

```
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video'),
    numVideos = videos.length;
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zr6Je/)

Comment: That looks like a great solution. Thank you! Will I have issues if I am creating these `<video>` tags dynamically in JS? I basically need the CURRENT amount of videos, I assume this should work.

Comment: @KriiV You could wrap the code above in a function and let it return the "current" amount of videos. So each time you'd need the current amount you could do something like `var videos = getCurrentAmountOfVideos()`. See http://jsfiddle.net/zr6Je/2/ for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
   document.querySelectorAll('video').length
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/n6Z8a/

As mentioned below, `document.getElementsByTagName('video').length` is a faster (and better) solution.

Comment: Why bother with `querySelectorAll()`? `getElementsByTagName()` will be a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var vidTags = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
        for(var i = 0; i < vidTags.length; i++){
          //do something to each video
        }
```